# Convert curl command to PHP code

Tags: php, rest, curl

I need to delete opencast matterhorn recording via REST api which they already provided. (just for the information, no need to worry about matterhorn)

I need to develop simple PHP code to `DELETE` some entries via given REST API. I have tested with curl command line it is working fine, but I can't convert that into working PHP code.

working curl command :

```
curl --digest -X "DELETE" -u matterhorn_system_account:CHANGE_ME -H "X-Requested-Auth: Digest" -H "X-Opencast-Matterhorn-Authorization: true" url/search/xxxx
```

not working PHP command :

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'url/search/xxxx');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_DIGEST);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'matterhorn_system_account:CHANGE_ME');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-Requested-Auth: Digest"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-Opencast-Matterhorn-Authorization: true"));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
```

result `$httpCode` is 302, means it's not working.

Any idea where I went wrong.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine these two so you aren't overwriting yourself:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-Requested-Auth: Digest"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-Opencast-Matterhorn-Authorization: true"));
```

So that should be

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-Requested-Auth: Digest", 
                                           "X-Opencast-Matterhorn-Authorization: true"));
```

And it probably would also help to follow redirects with

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
```

Comment: you save my day, its works for me. with and without `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`, it works